# Problem with adding texture to triangle using SOIL in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, soil

This is an error that appears when trying to load the texture:
[image]This is my working directory:
[image]
Down below is the location of my texture images
[image]I tried adding a texture to a triangle however something seems to go wrong. When trying to run debug there is no error and no warning however it shows an grey window with no triangle and no texture whatsoever. Here is a part of my code, what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define GLEW_STATIC


#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

int glWindowWidth = 640;
int glWindowHeight = 480;
int retina_width, retina_height;
GLFWwindow* glWindow = NULL;

GLfloat vertexCoordinates[] = {
    //position         //color           //texture
    0.5f,0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,   1.0f ,1.0f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,   1.0f,0.0f
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,   0.0f ,0.0f,
    -0.5f,0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,   0.0f ,1.0f,
};
GLuint indices[] = 
{
0,1,2,  
1,2,3
};


GLuint verticesVBO;
GLuint triangleVAO;
GLuint EBO;




GLuint triangleVAO2;
GLuint verticesVBO2;


GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint shaderProgram2;



void windowResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "window resized to width: %d , and height: %d\n", width, height);
    //TODO
}

void initObjects()
{
    //genereaza un ID unic pentru verticesVBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &verticesVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &triangleVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexCoordinates), vertexCoordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //genereaza un ID unic, care corespunde obiectului triangleVAO

    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);

    //seteaza pointer-ul atributelor de varf
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    //de-selecteaza obiectul triangleVAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);




}

bool initOpenGLWindow()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return false;
    }

    //for Mac OS X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GL_FALSE);

    glWindow = glfwCreateWindow(glWindowWidth, glWindowHeight, "OpenGL Shader Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!glWindow) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(glWindow, windowResizeCallback);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glWindow);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    //for RETINA display
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(glWindow, &retina_width, &retina_height);

    return true;
}

void renderScene()
{
    //initializeaza buffer-ele de culoare si adancime inainte de a rasteriza cadrul curent
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //defineste culoarea de fundal
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    //specifica locatia si dimensiunea ferestrei
    glViewport(0, 0, retina_width, retina_height);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    if (glfwGetKey(glWindow, GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        //TODO
    }

    //activeaza program shader-ul; apeluri ulterioare de rasterizare vor utiliza acest program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram); /**/

    //activeaza VAO
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    //specifica tipul primitiei, indicele de inceput si numarul de indici utilizati pentru rasterizare
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); /**/



}

std::string readShaderFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream shaderFile;
    std::string shaderString;

    //open shader file
    shaderFile.open(fileName);

    std::stringstream shaderStringStream;

    //read shader content into stream
    shaderStringStream << shaderFile.rdbuf();

    //close shader file
    shaderFile.close();

    //convert stream into GLchar array
    shaderString = shaderStringStream.str();
    return shaderString;
}

void shaderCompileLog(GLuint shaderId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check compilation info
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader compilation error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

void shaderLinkLog(GLuint shaderProgramId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check linking info
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader linking error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

GLuint initBasicShader(std::string vertexShaderFileName, std::string fragmentShaderFileName, GLuint shaderProgram)
{
    //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
    std::string v = readShaderFile(vertexShaderFileName);
    const GLchar* vertexShaderString = v.c_str();
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderString, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    //check compilation status
    shaderCompileLog(vertexShader);

    //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
    std::string f = readShaderFile(fragmentShaderFileName);
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderString = f.c_str();
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderString, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //check compilation status
    shaderCompileLog(fragmentShader);

    //attach and link the shader programs
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    //check linking info
    shaderLinkLog(shaderProgram);

    return shaderProgram;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    initOpenGLWindow();

    initObjects();

    shaderProgram = initBasicShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag",shaderProgram);
    shaderProgram2 = initBasicShader("shaders/shader2.vert", "shaders/shader2.frag",shaderProgram2);
    int width, height;
    GLuint texture;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("res/images/image1.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glWindow)) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glfwPollEvents();
        renderScene();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "diffuseTexture"), 0);
        glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
        glfwSwapBuffers(glWindow);
    }

    //close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the fragment shader

```c
#version 400
in vec3 colour;
in vec2 passTexture;
out vec4 fragmentColour;
uniform sampler2D dif;
void main() {
    fragmentColour = texture(dif, passTexture);
}
```

This is the vertex shader:

```c
#version 400
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 textcoord;
out vec3 colour;
out vec2 passTexture;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main() {
    colour = vertexNormal;
    passTexture = textcoord;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all fields of the matrices in the vertex are shader are initialized by 0.0.

To make the code run you've to skip the matrices:

```c
gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

Or initialize them by the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) in `renderScene`:

```cpp
GLint model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
GLint view_loc  = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
GLint proj_loc  = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
GLint tex_loc   = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "diffuseTexture");

float identity_matrix[] = {1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1};
```

Note, uniforms have to be set, after the program is installed by `glUseProgram`.

```cpp
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc,  1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc,  1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
glUniform1i(tex_loc, 0); // unnecessary, because 0 is default.
```

---

Since the [`Index buffers`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) is stated in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers), the VAO has to be bound, before the index buffer can be bound:

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &triangleVAO);
glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

---

Set all the necessary states, and bind the necessary objects, before you do the draw call.
The viewport rectangle and the clear color should be set before `glClear`.
The texture should be bound before the mesh is drawn.

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glWindow)) {
    glfwPollEvents();        

    renderScene();

    glfwSwapBuffers(glWindow);
}
```

```cpp
void renderScene()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, retina_width, retina_height);
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    // set the uniforms as described above
    // [...]

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

---

Furthermore there is missing a comma (`,`) int the 2nd row of the array of vertex array attributes and the indices do not form a quad. Change it:

```cpp
GLfloat vertexCoordinates[] = {
    //position         //color           //texture
     0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  1.0f ,1.0f,
     0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,  1.0f ,0.0f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  0.0f ,0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,  0.0f ,1.0f,
};
GLuint indices[] = { 0,1,2, 0,2,3 };
```

---

Finally, if you want to use [mipmaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), then the texture minification filter has to be one of `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST`, `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` or `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

---

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

int glWindowWidth = 640;
int glWindowHeight = 480;
int retina_width, retina_height;
GLFWwindow* glWindow = NULL;

GLfloat vertexCoordinates[] = {
    //position         //color           //texture
     0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  1.0f ,1.0f,
     0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,  1.0f ,0.0f,
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,  0.0f ,0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f,0.0f,    1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,  0.0f ,1.0f,
};
GLuint indices[] = { 0,1,2, 0,2,3 };

GLuint verticesVBO;
GLuint triangleVAO;
GLuint EBO;
GLuint triangleVAO2;
GLuint verticesVBO2;
GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint shaderProgram2;
GLuint texture;
GLint model_loc, view_loc, proj_loc, tex_loc;
float identity_matrix[] = {1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1};

void windowResizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "window resized to width: %d , and height: %d\n", width, height);
    //TODO
}

void initObjects()
{
    //genereaza un ID unic pentru verticesVBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &verticesVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &triangleVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexCoordinates), vertexCoordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //genereaza un ID unic, care corespunde obiectului triangleVAO

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);

    //seteaza pointer-ul atributelor de varf
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8*sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    //de-selecteaza obiectul triangleVAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

bool initOpenGLWindow()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return false;
    }

    //for Mac OS X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GL_FALSE);

    glWindow = glfwCreateWindow(glWindowWidth, glWindowHeight, "OpenGL Shader Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!glWindow) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(glWindow, windowResizeCallback);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glWindow);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    //for RETINA display
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(glWindow, &retina_width, &retina_height);

    return true;
}

void renderScene()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, retina_width, retina_height);
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);

    if (glfwGetKey(glWindow, GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        //TODO
    }

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc,  1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc,  1, GL_FALSE, identity_matrix);
    glUniform1i(tex_loc, 0); // unnecessary, because 0 is default.

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

std::string readShaderFile(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream shaderFile;
    std::string shaderString;

    //open shader file
    shaderFile.open(fileName);

    std::stringstream shaderStringStream;

    //read shader content into stream
    shaderStringStream << shaderFile.rdbuf();

    //close shader file
    shaderFile.close();

    //convert stream into GLchar array
    shaderString = shaderStringStream.str();
    return shaderString;
}

void shaderCompileLog(GLuint shaderId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check compilation info
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader compilation error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

void shaderLinkLog(GLuint shaderProgramId)
{
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    //check linking info
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgramId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "Shader linking error\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
}

GLuint initBasicShader(std::string vertexShaderFileName, std::string fragmentShaderFileName, GLuint shaderProgram)
{
    //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
    std::string v = readShaderFile( vertexShaderFileName );
    const GLchar* vertexShaderString = v.c_str();
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderString, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    //check compilation status
    shaderCompileLog(vertexShader);

    //read, parse and compile the vertex shader
    std::string f = readShaderFile( fragmentShaderFileName );
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderString = f.c_str();
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderString, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //check compilation status
    shaderCompileLog(fragmentShader);

    //attach and link the shader programs
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    //check linking info
    shaderLinkLog(shaderProgram);

    return shaderProgram;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    initOpenGLWindow();

    initObjects();

    shaderProgram = initBasicShader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag",shaderProgram);

    model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
    view_loc  = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
    proj_loc  = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
    tex_loc   = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "diffuseTexture");

    shaderProgram2 = initBasicShader("shaders/shader2.vert", "shaders/shader2.frag",shaderProgram2);
    int width, height;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("SOIL2/res/images/image1.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(glWindow)) {
        glfwPollEvents();        

        renderScene();

        glfwSwapBuffers(glWindow);
    }

    //close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Tried all this but still a grey window appears . Literally no clue to what is wrong

Comment: @Lola I'm very sure that your texture is not loaded. Disable blending (delete  `glEnable(GL_BLEND);`) for debug reasons. Now you should get a black rectangle in the middle of the gray window. If that is the case, then use an absolute path rather than the relative path.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem of texture, not sure how to solve it yet though, tried with absolute path also however relative path should work as the current working directory is good relative to the picture. To be more exact it prints "failed to load texture: 4"

Comment: I added a pic of working directory and where texture images are placed in the question

Comment: If I try that path a weird error appears when I debug it (also the shaders is in the same directory as SOIL2 and SOIL2 does have the res folder in it)--added that error too in the question

Comment: I actually think that that might be the right path but this error appears out of nowhere related to a library..(I see there is no more "failed to load texture" on the console)

Comment: @Lola The correct filepath is "SOIL2/res/images/image1.jpg" .

Comment: do you have any idea of what might cause this type of error? It appeared before but I'm really not sure and can't seem to find anything about it on the internet..

Comment: I was going to upvote this any way don't worry, it was of a lot of use and thank you very much for the struggle, it helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Lola Thank you. Do you use the most resent version of soil2 library. Can you try a different file or even file format (e.g. bmp or png)?

Answer (score 1):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//genereaza un ID unic, care corespunde obiectului triangleVAO

glBindVertexArray(triangleVAO);
```

You need to bind the vertex array object before you bind the index buffer, so you need to swap this around.

Edit: The vertex array bind needs to go above

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVBO);
```

as well.

Comment: I edited the post and added the fragment and vertex shader

Comment: In your vertex shader you use 3 uniform matrices, but you don't set them anywhere in your code.